# How to GetBytes from string appropriately?

Tags: c#, encoding

I have a string variable from which I get the following bytes with the following loop:

```
Bytes I get: 1e 05 55 3c *e2 *91 6f 03 *fe 1a 1d *f4 51 6a 5e 3a *ce *d1 04 *8c 

With that loop:

  byte[] temp = new byte[source.Length];
  string x = "";
  for (int i = 0;i != source.Length;i++)
  {
    temp[i] = ((byte) source[i]);
  }
```

Now I have wanted to simplify that operation and use Encoding's GetBytes.
The problem is I cannot fit an appropriate encoding. e.g. I get several bytes incorrect:

```
Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(source):    1e 05 55 3c *3f *3f 6f 03 *3f 1a 1d *3f 51 6a 5e 3a *3f *3f 04 *3f
Encoding.Default.GetBytes(source):  1e 05 55 3c  e2  3f 6f 03  3f 1a 1d  f4 51 6a 5e 3a  ce  4e 04  3f
```

How can I get rid of that loop and use Encoding's GetBytes?

Here is the summary:

```
Loop(correct bytes):                1e 05 55 3c *e2 *91 6f 03 *fe 1a 1d *f4 51 6a 5e 3a *ce *d1 04 *8c 

Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(source):    1e 05 55 3c *3f *3f 6f 03 *3f 1a 1d *3f 51 6a 5e 3a *3f *3f 04 *3f
Encoding.Default.GetBytes(source):  1e 05 55 3c  e2  3f 6f 03  3f 1a 1d  f4 51 6a 5e 3a  ce  4e 04  3f
```

Thanks!

Addition:

I have a string input in hex, sth like: "B1807869C20CC1788018690341"
then I transfer this into string with the method:

```
private static string hexToString(string sText)
{
  int i = 0;
  string plain = "";
  while (i < sText.Length)
  {
    plain += Convert.ToChar(Convert.ToInt32(sText.Substring(i, 2), 16));
    i += 2;
  }
  return plain;
}
```

Comment: How do you get the string `source` from the bytes?

Comment: could you provide the string in question?

Comment: @John, seriously: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @yas4891 ok, I noticed that I am transfering hex string to string and then to byte array. I could transfer straightforwardly from hex string to byte[] and that works ok.. But just for curiosity. How to do it correctly: hexString -> to string -> to byte array?

Comment: @John there is no single "correct" hexString -> to string -> to byte array; to go to/from `string`, you **really** need to know which `Encoding` it is in; if it is just arbitrary binary, then **it isn't a string**, and shouldn't be treated as such. Unless you cheat with 28591 (as per my answer)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your hexToString is transferring byte values (via hex) **directly** to unicode code-points in the range 0-255. As it happens, that ties into code-page 28591, so if you use:

```
Encoding enc = Encoding.GetEncoding(28591);
```

and use *that* `enc`, you should get the right data; however, a more important point here is that binary data is not the same as text data, and you should not use a `string` to hold arbitrary binary.

Comment: Works. Where do you know it from, it is 28591?

Comment: @John in order to answer this question, I wrote a console exe that  iterates all via `Encoding.GetEncodings()`, and tested all of them ;p http://pastie.org/2948555

Comment: @John but again: if the data isn't actually really text data, you shouldn't try to hold it in a `string`

Answer (score 3):

**Presuming that you are trying to "decode" a string literal:**
C# stores the strings as Unicode internally. 
So you might want to use a encoding that (correctly) supports Unicode

such as:

```
Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(source)
Encoding.UnicodeEncoding.GetBytes(source)
```

Note the caution given for `Encoding.Default` in [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.encoding.default.aspx)